# Get records 10 min before system datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

i need to find the records 10 min before system current datetime.

```
select Id,TimeStamp from ISAlive where RecordUpdatedDate < GETDATE() --SYSDATETIME()
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
select Id, TimeStamp
from ISAlive
WHERE RecordUpdatedDate = dateadd(minute,-10,getdate())
```

might be a starting point.  Of course, it probably won't match exactly...

...if you want to get the most recent record that fits that criteria, however, try

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, TimeStamp
FROM ISAlive
WHERE RecordUpdatedDate <= dateadd(minute, -10, getdate())
ORDER BY RecordUpdatedDate DESC
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with now()

```
SELECT Id, TimeStamp
FROM ISAlive 
WHERE RecordUpdatedDate <= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
```

Comment: This works if I surround '10 minutes' in quotes like so.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Id, TimeStamp
FROM ISAlive 
WHERE RecordUpdatedDate < DATEADD(minute,-10, SYSDATETIME());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE               
NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```